# How to send data of multiple tables through ajax call?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending data to a controller using JQuery, but controller is not recieveing any data.

I want to post data of two tables, the fields are dynamically created and some are in the html.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
{          
   coursesarray.push($("#coursename").val());          
   for (var i = 1; i < counter; i++)    
    {            
       var courses = $('#coursename' + i).val();         
       coursesarray.push(courses);        
    }   
    obj.tbl_course = coursesarray;       
    obj.Name = Name;

    $.ajax(
       {
       type: "POST",
       datatype: "json",
       contenttype: "application/json/",
       url: "/Demo/SaveData/",
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       success: savesuccess,
       error:saveerror
       });        
});
```

Controller Method

```
public JsonResult SaveData(tbl_name tblobj)
{
    db.tbl_name.Add(tblobj);
    db.SaveChanges();
    foreach (var a in tblobj.tbl_course)
    {
        db.tbl_course.Add(a);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And model is

```
public partial class tbl_name
{
    public int PkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_course> tbl_course { get; set; }
}
```

and second model is

```
public partial class tbl_course
{
    public int Pkid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FkId { get; set; }
    public string Coursename { get; set; }
    public string CourseTeacher { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_name tbl_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your controller method you posting to and the model your binding to.

Comment: i have posted everything please have a look.

Comment: try data: {tblobj:JSON.stringify(obj)},

Comment: Propery `tbl_course` is a collection of complex objects. You code to populate the javascript array needs to be objects representing a `tbl_course` - e.g. `coursesarray.push({ Pkid: 1, FkId: 1, Coursename: "xxx', ..... });`

Comment: But its really unclear what your trying to do here and why you would have controls with terrible id attributes (`e.g. $('#coursename' + i)`) instead of just binding to your model.

Comment: make sue you are sending and receiving correct parameters. Even if a single spelling mistek will trouble you.

Comment: You need to show the relevant view code to understand how you generating your view because your taking a poor approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

I have my class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

And my `Shop` class is like this

```
public class Shop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AddressContd { get; set; }
    public ShopContacts ShopContacts { get; set; }
}
```

And my `ShopContacts` class is just like a simple class, including fname, lname etc properties.

My controller method is like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(Customer Data)
{
      ...
}
```

And my jQuery/Ajax is like this,

```
var contacts = {
                FirstName: $("#firstName").val(),
                LastName: $("#lastName").val(),
                Email: $("#email").val(),
            };
var ShopsData = [{
                Name: $("#ptLocAddr").val(),
                Address: $("#ptLocAddr").val(),
                AddressContd: $("#ptLocAddrContd").val(),
                Country: $("#ptLocCountry").val(),
                State: $("#ptLocState").val(),
                City: $("#ptLocCity").val(),
                Zip: $("#zip").val(),
                FacilityType: $("#ptFacility").val(),
                Radius: $("#ptShopRadius").val(),
                ShopContacts: contacts
            }]
var Data = {
                id: 0,
                Shops: ShopsData
            }

$.ajax({
     "url": "http://localhost:63025/api/values/",
     "type": "Post",
     "data":Data,
     success: function (d) {
         console.log(d);
     }
})
```

And it's working as expected. In your case just add the values using push() method in jQuery and follow the way I'm doing.

```
var myArray = [];
```

Here you can do the .each() and push the value to the array like this below:

```
myArray.push(yourForEachData);
```

Then

```
 var myData = {
            RuleID: $('#hidRuleId').val(),
            ProcessDefnID: $('#hidProcessDefnId').val(),
            RuleName: $('#txtEditRuleName').val(),
            Conditions: Conditions,
            ...
       }
```

And in your ajax method just place the myData in data field, like this

```
{
...,
data: myData,
...,
}
```

That's it! It will work definitely. Just change the class name, variable name and properties to match with your requirements.